# Module visibility in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a Rust project that has the following directory structure:

```
src-
   |
   amd64-
   |    |
   |    fp64.rs
   |    mod.rs
   |
   fp.rs
```

Inside `src/amd64/mod.rs` I only have the following line of code `pub mod fp64;`. Inside `src/fp.rs`, I tried to do something like this:

```
pub use amd64::fp64::*;
pub type Element = amd64::fp64::Element;
```

This throws an error because it apparently cannot find `amd64`. If I switch to using just `use amd64::fp64::*`, then I get error in multiple files that there is no `Element`, so it kind of skips the above type assignment. Please note that `Element` inside `amd64/fp64` is a struct. `Element` inside `amd64/fp64.rs` is defined such as this: `pub struct Element(pub (crate) [u64; 12]);`.

Comment: Try `use amd64::fp64::*;` (drop `pub`).

Comment: @ljedrz Thanks, but see my modified question. If I drop `pub` the complains about `amd64` not being present are gone, but other files complain that they cannot find `Element`.

Comment: Showing the `Element`-revelant code might help here. In addition, why the type alias `pub type Element = amd64::fp64::Element;`? `Element` should already work as as shorthand for `amd64::fp64::Element` after the import.

Comment: @ljedrz Because, I use conditional compilation, depending on the architecture I assign different definition of `Element`. The above is just a small snippet. In any case, `Element` is defined such as this `pub struct Element(pub (crate) [u64; 12]);`

Comment: Library or Executable project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you need to add a new `src/lib.rs` file containing the following lines:

```
pub mod fp;
pub mod amd64;
```