# How to split the code in modules in Rust?

Tags: module, compiler-errors, rust

I am reading the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-modules-and-use-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html#separating-modules-into-different-files), I am in the chapter 7.2, but I must be missing something, because I cannot organize my code in modules, the compiler (rustc 1.32.0) keeps giving me errors.

### What I have read

- I read `rustc --explain E0433`, which is the advice of the compiler, but I still cannot solve it.
- I checked [Rust by examples](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/mod/split.html), and it seems that my code is correct, (`my/mod.rs` is using module `my/nested.rs` in its own folder)
- I found some info on Internet, but it is of 4 years ago, and include the use of `use`, which is not yet in the book.
- I also checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48136879/module-visibility-in-rust), but I am not using folders, and again, it gets away from the book explanation.

### Minimal example

This is a minimal example that tries to mimic the "sound" example of the book, there is only two files: `/src/main.rs` and `/src/m.rs`.

main.rs

```
mod m;
fn main() {
  let st_0 = m::St::new();
}
```

m.rs

```
pub mod m {
    pub struct St {
        a:i32,
        b:i32,
    }
    impl St {
        pub fn new() -> St{
            println!("New St!");
            St {
                a: 12,
                b: 13,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what `cargo` tells me:

```
   Compiling min v0.1.0 (/home/user/min)
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `St` in `m`
 --> src/main.rs:3:19
  |
3 |     let st_0 = m::St::new();
  |                   ^^ could not find `St` in `m`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
error: Could not compile `min`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Comment: It certainly is a duplicate, I didn't catch it before. What should I do with my question? Delete it?

Answer (score 1):

When you have everything in one file, like this:

main.rs

```
pub mod m {
    pub struct St {
        a:i32,
        b:i32,
    }
    impl St {
        pub fn new() -> St{
            println!("New St!");
            St {
                a: 12,
                b: 13,
            }
        }
    }
}

mod m;
fn main() {
  let st_0 = m::St::new();
}
```

you wrap the module with the

```
pub mod mode_name {
    //code...
}
```

Once you put the module in another file, **that wrapping goes away**. [The Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-modules-and-use-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html#separating-modules-into-different-files), shows it, but if you don't look carefully <strike>or if you are programming drunk</strike>, you may get confused with the `pub mod instrument {...}` of the nested module.

So m.rs has to look like this:

```
pub struct St {
    a:i32,
    b:i32,
}
impl St {
    pub fn new() -> St{
        println!("New St!");
        St {
            a: 12,
            b: 13,
        }
    }
}
```